# Implementation of pusher for android app

Tags: java, android, push-notification, salesforce, pusher

I am beginner to pusher . I want to integrate pusher in android app , eventually i have done this. But i want to make connection of my app with pusher alive when android app is in inactive state.

Is this possible to make connection when application is not running.

and one more question associated with above is:

Can we use pusher for the purpose of push notification in android when my server is on salesforce .

Comment: can you explain? what is `pusher`?

Comment: Pusher is mediator between client and server to deliver messages.            You can learn more about it from this [link](http://pusher.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pusher from the background service. Just make a connection from the android background service.

Comment: Thanks @BeingMIAkashs  Can we use pusher for the purpose of push notification ?

Comment: If your server support websocket then you can user pusher

Comment: "If your server support websocket then you can user pusher" - this is not correct. Your *server* doesn't need to support WebSocket to use Pusher. The only server requirement is that it can make an outgoing HTTP request to interact with Pusher's Web API. You can use Pusher to send custom notifications (messages/events) to an Android device. However, these are not native Push Notifications.